# JmDNS to detect network devices in Android

Tags: android, jmdns

I am using JmDNS API to detect all the devices connected on the network.

I am able to detect devices and list them out. But there is a small problem.
My app is displaying machines which are running only linux.

Can somebody throw light on this??I am using Samsung Galaxy S2 to test my app.

Comment: I am actually trying to find a network printer here

Comment: I know that if I install iTunes then JmDNS will detect the Bonjour services which get installed with iTunes. But its not feasible for me to install iTunes on each and every system.

Can somebody please answer?

Comment: How do you detect all services in code? I only saw jmDNS example to list specific services. Thx!

Comment: @German: It's been a long time. Need to look into that code..Will send you the code once I get hold of it. I hope it's not very urgent for you..:)

Answer (score 0):

Do not have a solution to your jmdns problem, but you may want to try searching with a PC tool to see if the printers are really visible.

You can get an add-on for Firefox
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dnssd/

Or a standalone tool
http://hobbyistsoftware.com/bonjourbrowser

And see if the printer you are looking for shows up on the list